# I am trying to make a main class in processing (java) using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing

I am currently using processing in IntelliJ. Usually when i use processing when i create a file it starts off as a sort of "main project" then i can create new classes. 
However in intelliJ, I am starting off with a class, and making more classes. So then the global variables i use in main part of the program won't pass to the classes.

for example in processing i do this

```
global variables
classes
void setup()
{
   code....
}
void draw()
{
   code...
   calling classes

}
```

then in the class

```
class example
{
   void example2()
   {
     code using global variable
   }
}
```

however in intellij i start off with

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

    public class program
    {
  global variables
    classes
    void setup()
    {
       code....
    }
    void draw()
    {
       code...
       calling classes

    }
```

Then when i go to make class it doesnt get the global variables.

Anyone know?

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]?

Comment: Like cricket_007 says, we need to see a complete example. We need to see exactly where your classes are: are they inner classes or not? We need to see how you're launching your application: where is your `main()` method. But note that this should **not** be your entire project, but just enough code for us to copy and paste to run ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the processing `core.jar` file somewhere on your classpath, a basic processing sketch would look like this:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MySketch extends PApplet {

    @Override
    public void setup() {
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { MySketch.class.getName() });
    }
```

Getting it set up to work in intellij can be difficult due to the fact that you need the `gluegen-rt` and `jogl` libraries on the classpath as well.  Processing uses those libraries to do the actual rendering.

If you're familiar with [maven](https://maven.apache.org/), I've created a tool to let you install the processing dependencies and all the contributed libraries into your local maven repo. It's called [processing-deps](http://github.com/josephtaylor/processing-deps)

Instructions for gettting that set up are in the README of that project.

But basically you'll end up with `pom.xml` file that has at bare-minimum this in it to get the the dependencies pulled in:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my-group-id</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
        <artifactId>processing-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```